# How to download an installed dbfs jar file from databricks cluster to local machine?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am new to Databricks and I wish to download an installed library of a databricks cluster to my local machine. Could you please help me with that?

So to elaborate I already have a running cluster on which libraries are already installed. I need to download some of those libraries (which are dbfs jar files) to my local machine. I actually have been trying to use the '''dbfs cp''' command through the databricks-cli but that is not working. It is not giving any error but it's not doing anything either. I hope that clears things a bit.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question ? What are you trying to achieve in the end and what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** When you installed libraries via `Jars`, `Maven`, `PyPI`, those are located in the folderpath `dbfs:/FileStore`.

[image]

- For Interactive cluster Jars located at - `dbfs:/FileStore/jars`
- For Automated cluster Jars located at - `dbfs:/FileStore/job-jars`

**There are couple of ways to download an installed dbfs jar file from databricks cluster to local machine.**

> **GUI Method:** You can use DBFS Explorer

DBFS Explorer was created as a quick way to upload and download files to the Databricks filesystem (DBFS). This will work with both AWS and Azure instances of Databricks.

You will need to create a bearer token in the web interface in order to connect.

**Step1:** Download DBFS explorer from Here:https://datathirst.net/projects/dbfs-explorer and install.

**Step2:** How to create a bearer token?

- Click the **user profile icon User Profile** in the upper right corner of
  your Databricks workspace.
- Click **User Settings**.
- Go to the **Access Tokens** tab.
- Click the **Generate New Token** button.

**Note:** Copy the generated token and store in a secure location.

[image]

**Step3:** Open DBFS explorer for Databricks and Enter `Host URL` and `Bearer Token` and continue.

[image]

**Step4:** Navigate to the DBFS folder named FileStore => jars => Select the jar which you want to download and click download and select the folder on the local machine.

[image]

> **CLI Method:** You can use Databricks CLI

**Step1:** Install the [Databricks CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/), configure it with your Databricks credentials.

**Step2:** Use the CLI "dbfs cp" command used to Copy files to and from DBFS.

**Syntax:** `dbfs cp <SOURCE> <DESTINATION>`

**Example:** `dbfs cp "dbfs:/FileStore/azure.txt" "C:\Users\Name\Downloads\"`

[image]

Comment: do you have info where the use of "job-jars" directory comes from? is it a Databricks recommendation, or just an convention you practice?